# Angular 4 firebase wait service to be loaded first

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am using Angular 4 with firebase and I need to wait my service to be loaded and then create FirebaseListObservable from my database..
my component.ts code is the following

```
constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase,public authService: AuthService,public 
    afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {  
        this.challenges = db.list('challenges', {
          query: {
            orderByChild: 'challenged',
            equalTo: this.authService.cusername
          }
        });
```

The problem is that the constructor gets the **authService.cusername** as undendifed because authService hasn't been fully loaded.. is there any way I can wait service to be loaded first and then run the `db.list('challenges', { etc...});` ?? I tried to do the some on ngOnInit but it seems I can use the **db: AngularFireDatabase** only in the constructor..

Answer (score 0):

Just add `private` or `public` keyword before `db:`, that will make the parameter also class field so you can access it in other methods via `this.db`:

```
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase,public authService: AuthService,public 
afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.db.doSomething();
}
```

This is basically just a syntax sugar in typescript:

```
constructor(private service: MyServiceType) {}
```

is the same as:

```
private service: MyServiceType;

constructor(service: MyServiceType) {
    this.service = service;
}
```